# How to share and modify data between view models in SwiftUI?

Tags: rest, swiftui, mvvm, ios16

I am making a social media app in SwiftUI and I am stuck on how to share and modify data between view models. For each view (PostListView, PostDetailView, PostUpdateView) I have a separate view model and when the user is on PostUpdateView,for example, and does changes to the post in PostUpdateViewModel, how do I reflect these changes on the PostListView?

```swift
// parent view model
class PostListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var posts = [Post]() // i want changes to any post to be reflected here 

    func fetchPosts() { ... } // fetches posts from rest api, called if self.posts is empty
}
```

```swift
// child view model
class PostUpdateViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var post: Post // when updated, i want to see the updated post on the PostListView

    init(post: Post) { self.post = post }

    func update() { ... } // update post api call
}
```

```swift
struct Post: Codable, Identifiable {
   var id: Int
   var title: String
   var content: String
   // other properties
}
```

So far I've seen people just refetch the data whenever they go back to the view containing the list of data, but that solution doesn't really work for me as my data is paginated, and when refetching, it just fetches the first page and sends the user back to the top of their feed. Two possible solutions I've thought of are either having one shared view model between all the views, regarding posts, or instead of storing the posts themselves in the parent view model, to store a list of child view models.

Thanks!

Comment: ViewModels aren’t supposed to share data or even know about each other. If they need access to the same data the data should be moved down to a manager. But also a note, SwiftUI is not designed to play well with MVVM, you should go through the Apple SwiftUI tutorials. There are some specific scenarios where it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when I need to share data between different views I put that data in a data store or aggregate model. This is shown below:

```
class CatalogStore: ObservableObject {
    
    private var storeHTTPClient: StoreHTTPClient
    
    init(storeHTTPClient: StoreHTTPClient) {
        self.storeHTTPClient = storeHTTPClient
    }
    
    @Published var products: [Product] = []
    @Published var categories: [Category] = []
    
    func addProduct(_ product: Product) async throws {
         try await storeHTTPClient.addProduct(product)
    }
    
    func populateProducts() async throws {
        self.products = try await storeHTTPClient.loadProducts()
    }
}
```

Now, I can inject an instance of CatalogStore into the enviromentObject and access it from all the views.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would just do it like this:

```
class PostUpdateView : View {
    let postID: UUID
    @State var post: Post?

    var body: some View {
         Text(post.title ?? "Loading...")
         .task(id: postID){
             if postID == post?.id { return } // prevent re-downloading on re-appear
             post = await fetchPost(id: postID)
         } 
    }
}
```

It's best to avoid classes in Swift/SwiftUI whenever you can because it leads to consistency bugs, task manages an object for you and has the right behaviour, init on appear, cancel and deinit on dissapear etc. which is tricky to get right yourself.